# Inserting Dates into Mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a huge file with dates in the format 'DD-MMM-YY', eg. '14-JUL-14'. 
If I directly `LOAD DATA INFILE` then the date columns are left blank.

What can be the best way to import these dates? I can run a script to convert all the dates into MySQL readable formates, but I want to avoid doing that on a ~20GB file.

Comment: I think the duplicate answers your question.